# setShowsUserLocation property - why does this not work?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

In an exercise I am doing involving MKMapView, I was instructed to enter the following line in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` :

```
[mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
```

I expected this to zoom me into my location, but it did not.

After carefully reviewing the MapView in Interface Builder, I noticed in the Attributes window a checkbox to toggle "Shows User Location". Suddenly the zoom worked. I commented out the other line and it still works, which begs the question - why did it fail in the first place?

I'm using the latest iPhone SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That doesn't zoom to the location, it only tells the mapview to display the small blue dot. You'll have to move the mapview there yourself.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't even see the blue dot until the zoom was set.